# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that are related to each other.  When It try to do an insert, I get the error message:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`Token`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Token_my_aspnet_users_id` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`UserId`) REFERENCES `my_aspnet_users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION)

Here is the script for both tables:

**Token**

```
CREATE TABLE Token (
  Id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UserId INT(11) NOT NULL,
  Token CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Token_my_aspnet_users_id FOREIGN KEY (UserId)
    REFERENCES my_aspnet_users(id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 7
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

**my_aspnet_users**

```
CREATE TABLE my_aspnet_users (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  applicationId INT(11) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  isAnonymous TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  lastActivityDate DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX fk_users_applications_idx (applicationId),
  CONSTRAINT fk_users_applications FOREIGN KEY (applicationId)
    REFERENCES my_aspnet_applications(id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 364
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 83
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Comment: Show the insert query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

verify if the token id that you trying to insert really exists